# Non-interactive user authentication using AAD v2

Tags: azure, asp.net-web-api, azure-active-directory

We are exposing a service written in ASP .net Core Web API, and using AAD V2 and claims based authentication.
Our clients use Microsoft and MSA accounts which are supported in the V2.

We have a requirement which the consumer need to consume our Web API from a windows service.(non-interactive)
We understand that the resource owner password credentials are not supported in the AAD V2.

We tried using the client secret approach, but we cannot distinguish a particular user form this approach as we are not getting a UPN or unique value.
Can you please let us know if there is an alternate approach which we can use in this scenario.

Answer (score 0):

Well,

if you are required to authenticate from a Windows Service, this automatically eliminates the Authorization Code and ROPC flows. Simply because you do not have a user context. That's why you also do not need an ID Token. In that case, you only need an Access Token. There is an [interesting reading on the Auth0 blogs here](https://auth0.com/blog/why-should-use-accesstokens-to-secure-an-api/).

Having said that, I would suggest that you create a separate application registration for **each** of your Windows Service clients that would use your WebAPI. You can also automatically "grant" access to the Web API for each of those apps in the developer portal.

While, you keep your single "Web App" application registration for the user interactive flows. Still as a **separate** application registration with grants to the Web API.

And again - reconsider using only **Access Tokenss** to access your Web API.

To close - I am not sure if the Client Credentials flow is **fully** supported on the v.2.0, but it is definitely the way to go.

Comment: Client Credentials flow is supported on the v.2.0. Please check for details here - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-v2-protocols-oauth-client-creds. 

However, the v2.0 endpoint doesn't support all Azure Active Directory scenarios and features. To determine whether you should use the v2.0 endpoint, read about v2.0 limitations - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-v2-limitations

Answer (score -1):

You can Get a user token silently. You can use MSAL cache and get the token silently.

Here is a example:

You can use MSAL again here to fetch access_tokens from the MSAL cache. First, add a using statement for MSAL to this file.

```
using Microsoft.Identity.Client;
```

In the Index action, use MSAL's AcquireTokenSilentAsync method to get an access_token that can be used to read data from the To-Do List service:

```
// ...
string userObjectID = ClaimsPrincipal.Current.FindFirst("http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/nameidentifier").Value;
string tenantID = ClaimsPrincipal.Current.FindFirst("http://schemas.microsoft.com/identity/claims/tenantid").Value;
string authority = String.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, Startup.aadInstance, tenantID, string.Empty);
ClientCredential credential = new ClientCredential(Startup.clientId, Startup.clientSecret);

// Here you ask for a token using the web app's clientId as the scope, since the web app and service share the same clientId.
app = new ConfidentialClientApplication(Startup.clientId, redirectUri, credential, new NaiveSessionCache(userObjectID, this.HttpContext)){};
result = await app.AcquireTokenSilentAsync(new string[] { Startup.clientId });
// ...
```

Here is [the source document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-v2-devquickstarts-webapp-webapi-dotnet#call-the-web-api) for .Net App. But its method should also work on .Net Core App.

Comment: As informed in my question this approach would not work, API need to know  which user  invoked the API, the UPN is missing in the access token created in the sample code given.  I would like to distinguish the caller.

Comment: Hi,@arunmudiraj . If you really want to get the user's upn and other information. you may need get the `Id_token`. the client credentials grant flow cannot achieve this. So you may use OAuth 2.0 Authorization Code Flow. You will get `Id_token` in this flow and `id_token` contains `preferred_username` and `email` claims. But it use refresh token to get token agin.

Comment: The client credential flow required an Interactive UI to be displayed, which is not feasible,  we are looking for some thing similar to https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/wushuai/2016/09/25/resource-owner-password-credentials-grant-in-azure-ad-oauth/

Comment: Does this help with your scenario - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-authentication-scenarios#daemon-or-server-application-to-web-api

Comment: Given approach is for AAD v1 not AAD v2

Comment: for AAD v2 check this out - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-v2-flows#daemons-and-server-side-apps

Comment: GitHub sample - https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-daemon-v2